# A generalization of the concept of affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying Fulton's book and in the chapter $6$, he gives a definition of variety.
Before that he defines the affine variety in the chapter 2:

The definition of affine variety is

[image]

The definition of variety:

[image]

This definition of variety is a generalization of the concept of affine variety? I couldn't see why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part of being a generalization do you not see? The part about an affine variety being a variety, or that there are non-affine varieties?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft An affine variety $K$ is a variety because we can take $V=K$, am I right?

Comment: Not quite. For example, the $V$ in the definition of variety could be projective.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft you're right, so I don't see any two parts of the generalization.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft wait, I don't understand, in particular $V$ could be a set in $\mathbb A^n$

Comment: Yes, it could. But in the given definition, $V$ could be many things. You can certainly pick things in such a way that $K$ and $V$ coincide, but you need to pick things correctly. My main objection to your first comment is that $V$ is not really something fixed in this case that it makes sens to set $K$ equal to.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think I understood your point, $V$ is not fixed. In this way, any irreducible algebraic subset $K$ of $\mathbb A^n$ is a variety because it's open in the induced topology on $K$. Am I right?